# libjpeg library missing for bookshop princexml install on Ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, princexml

I installed bookshop on my Ubuntu 12 install and followed the instructions for installing PrinceXML. I am getting the following error when executing prince:

> /usr/lib/prince/bin/prince: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 6):

libjpeg is part of the libjpeg62 package so try this first:

```
@ubuntu~$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, only in a different app using the same lib.
My U12.04 is 64-bit, therefore way around is to install 32-bit lib version.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg:32
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an equivalent issue with my ubuntu 12.10 and png2swf utility.
Actually, `libjpeg.so.62` didn't exist. But it's likely a link to a hard file.

a `'locate libjpeg'` listed among others

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
```

My quick and dirty fix was to **create a symbolic link to libjpeg.so.8.0.2**, in superuser mode

> ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62

Bear in mind that some libs differ not that significantly across versions. Well, I was lucky but sometimes simple fixes might solve small issues, not always true though.

You may also wish to read about the ldd command, and verify that a missing shared-library is not present.